# PyCharm debugger disconnects from remote host after short idle time

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm, pydev

I've been using the PyDev/PyCharm debugger's remote debugging feature for years, and it's worked just fine. I've been using it for a Django-based project which runs in a Docker container for the last year or so, and it worked just fine with that, too.

But ever since a few months ago (possibly due to my code shop's switch to Python 3?), I've had no end of frustration with it because the debugger keeps disconnecting for no reason. I'll be in the middle of a debug session that's going just fine, but then if I let the system idle for about a minute, the debug session suddenly dies, and execution of the request goes on without me.

When that happens, I'll see the console output change from:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.3942.36)
```

To:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.3942.36)
Waiting for process connection...
```

And once this happens, the only solution to get the debugger to reconnect to the running Django server inside my container is to restart gunicorn, either through editing a file to make gunicorn reload itself, or through restarting the gunicorn application with `kill -HUP`. Further requests made against the server will not trigger any breakpoints unless I do that.

In addition, once this has happened, further debugging causes dozens of lines like this to appear in my container's log whnever I hit "Resume Program":

```
container-name    | Could not find thread pid_81_id_140102606217792
container-name    | Available: ['pid_232_id_140052765045312', 'pid_232_id_140052676863480', 'pid_232_id_140052644157928', 'pid_232_id_140052644157200', 'pid_232_id_140052660987328', 'pid_232_id_140052643054984']
container-name    | Could not find thread pid_81_id_140102606217792
container-name    | Available: ['pid_240_id_140052765045312', 'pid_240_id_140052676863480', 'pid_240_id_140052643056888', 'pid_240_id_140052644157200', 'pid_240_id_140052660987328', 'pid_240_id_140052643054984']
container-name    | Could not find thread pid_52_id_140052676829080
container-name    | Available: ['pid_240_id_140052765045312', 'pid_240_id_140052676863480', 'pid_240_id_140052643056888', 'pid_240_id_140052644157200', 'pid_240_id_140052660987328', 'pid_240_id_140052643054984']
container-name    | Could not find thread pid_232_id_140052765045312
container-name    | Available: ['pid_240_id_140052765045312', 'pid_240_id_140052676863480', 'pid_240_id_140052643056888', 'pid_240_id_140052644157200', 'pid_240_id_140052660987328', 'pid_240_id_140052643054984']
container-name    | Could not find thread pid_223_id_140052714764496
container-name    | Available: ['pid_240_id_140052765045312', 'pid_240_id_140052676863480', 'pid_240_id_140052643056888', 'pid_240_id_140052644157200', 'pid_240_id_140052660987328', 'pid_240_id_140052643054984']
```

The only thing that makes this stop happening is restarting the PyCharm debugger (which necessitates restarting gunicorn because I'm stuck at "Waiting for process connection...").

Perhaps I have my `pydevd.settrace()` in a bad place? It's in my wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from djunk.utils import getenv

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'multitenant.settings.settings')

# If the environment is configured to enable remote debugging, attach to the configured remote debug server.
# If REMOTE_DEBUG_ENABLED set to True, REMOTE_DEBUG_HOST and REMOTE_DEBUG_PORT are required.
if getenv('REMOTE_DEBUG_ENABLED', False):
    print('Debugging Enabled')
    # We keep this import inside the REMOTE_DEBUG_ENABLED check because simply doing the import slows down the process,
    # even if we don't call settrace().

    sys.path.insert(0, '/debug/pycharm-debug-py3k.egg')
    import pydevd
    # Attach to a Remote Debugger session running in PyCharm or PyDev on the configured host and port.
    # NOTE: If no remote debug server is running, this call will crash and the exception handler will also crash. 
    # Be aware of this!
    pydevd.settrace(
        host=getenv('REMOTE_DEBUG_HOST'),
        port=getenv('REMOTE_DEBUG_PORT'),
        suspend=False
    )

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Should I be doing this differently?

EDIT: It's worse than I'd realized. Simply letting the system sit idle for 40 seconds after seeing "Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.4301.16)", regardless of whether the debugger actually hits a breakpoint, the connection dies and goes back to "Waiting for process connection..."

Comment: Are you using the professional or community edition?

Comment: @Batman Professional Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the source of this problem purely through serendipity. It turns out that there was a configuration error made by the Docker for Mac devs in a recent edge build. They fixed it in the newest build, which just released today. When I checked the changelog, I noticed a bugfix which made me think "hmmm, that could be the source of this debugger timeout issue..." Installing the new build did, in fact, fix the problem.

What was happening was that the `vpnkit` software they use inside Docker for Mac was mistakenly configured to kill TCP connections after 30 seconds of idle time. The fix pushed that number back up to 300 seconds, which is far more bearable of a timeout when you're debugging.

I've left this question up, and answered it, just in case anyone else runs across this problem. The version of Docker for Mac that fixes this issue is 18.01.0-ce-mac48 (22004), currently available on the Edge channel.

Comment: Thanks for leaving this up @CoreDumpError! Hugely helpful in shining some light on my problem. Out of curiosity, are you still experiencing the `Could not find thread...` messages? Seem to be on my end but doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: @woootencl I don't recall seeing them recently, but I've been using a much spammier docker log filter, so it's possible that I'm missing them. 

However, since writing this post, I've also switched to a per-request debugger connection, rather than connecting the debugger when gunicorn starts. That might also affect the `Could not find thread...` messages.